# Flask server works on internal network but doesn't connect with VPN

Tags: python, flask, network-programming, remote-access, vpn

## SSH works everywhere

I recently obtained a static IP at work and attached it to an internal domain. I am able to SSH into the machine with `ssh MY_DOMAIN` regardless of whether I'm

1. physically at work and on the same network, or
2. connected with full-tunnel VPN.

---

## Flask works at work

If I'm physically at work and start a Flask server (code below) after logging into the desktop the domain is routed to, I can open up `MY_DOMAIN` in a browser on any computer *at work* (no VPN) and see `Hello There!`.

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80) # 127.0.0.1 didn't work either
    # changing host to MY_DOMAIN or IP and port to 5000, etc. also didn't work
```

If I'm away from work but on VPN and SSH into the machine to start the Flask server, my connection times out when navigating to `MY_DOMAIN` in a browser.

---

## Ping also works at work

- On VPN, when I `ping MY_DOMAIN`, I see `0 packets received` (all packets received when I'm at work):

```sh
9 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

- If I turn off VPN away from work and `ping MY_DOMAIN`, I see:

```sh
ping: cannot resolve MY_DOMAIN: Unknown host
```

---

How am I able to SSH without any issues when I'm at work or away and on VPN, but can't interact with my domain in any other way on VPN?

I suspect this could be related to ports but I have limited networking knowledge.

---

And yep, I've done my research. This was the closest question on here [connecting to flask app over VPN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44889727/connecting-to-flask-app-over-vpn?rq=1) but it doesn't help (at least I don't think I want to *deploy* anything). I don't know if this is possible, but I think I want to configure: "forward incoming requests on port 80 of MY_DOMAIN to Flask app on localhost, port 80". (Edit: don't know any more after the Apache Web server works.)

---

### Edit: I can connect to an Apache server on VPN but *not* Flask

I can navigate to `MY_DOMAIN` in a browser connected VPN and see "It Works" when I SSH and run:

```sh
sudo apachectl start
sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd Disabled -bool false
```

I wonder why this doesn't work with Flask.

(reference: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-make-my-iMac-the-hosting-for-my-website)

Comment: The error is pretty clear. Has nothing to do with ports. It can’t find the computer with the name that you typed (MY_DOMAIN). Check your DNS.

Comment: How do you know? When I ping MY_DOMAIN in VPN, it resolves to the correct router IP...

Comment: Sorry. I was going off the only error message you posted. I see now that was with VPN disabled. Any chance your VPN is configures to block traffic on certain ports?

Comment: I don't think so. Updated the question with info on an Apache server that I *can* connect to on VPN

Comment: You mentioned error messages: as mentioned, the request times out (I don't get an error).

Comment: Sometimes ping will work when TCP doesn’t if routing is not set up correctly. Maybe an asymmetric routing setup.

Comment: The static IP is a private one? If so then the DNS servers at work are correctly resolving it but not the ones provided by the VPN. As a workaround, try adding the mapping on /etc/hosts when behind the VPN or try a split DNS with `dnsmasq` in your box.

Comment: Yes, it’s static. And I will look into that! However, I recently added details mentioning how I can navigate (on VPN) to an Apache Web server hosted on the instance. This does not require me to be at work physically. This is exactly the behavior I want but with a simple flask server (I’m unable to use mod_wsgi). Given that the Apache Web server works, do you think it could still be a problem with how DNS servers work with VPN?